# What is needed to load/reload an addon during development?

Tags: python, add-on, linux

I wonder what is the best practice to develop an addon for blender on Linux.

To my understanding I need to place the python file that implements the addon
in `~/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addon`

In the content there needs to be the dict `bl_info`, containing some keys like `"name", "category", ...`
Also the functions `register()` and `unregister()` need to be there.

I have all this, but the addon is not shown in the list of addons, also after a refresh.

Is the location `~/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addon` not correct?

If I do changes to the file, how do i best get these changes into the running blender process?
I don't think I need to restart blender, each time I edit the addon source?

Comment: I think the folder is called "addons" and not "addon".
Does that solve your issue?

Comment: You can reload addons with *F8*.

Comment: I wrote an addon to help with installing. You can find it here: https://github.com/natecraddock/AddonDevelopmentTool

Comment: Welcome to the site :) For future reference it's preferred that posts be kept to one question, in order to keep things more organized for future visitors looking for answers to a similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the addon not get loaded?

The path should be `~/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons/`, not addon.

> How do I best get addon changes into the running blender process?

F8 can be used to reload the addons.

Comment: As a slightly unrelated suggestion, I prefer to only *symlink* the file to `.config/blender/.../addons`, so that the file itself is stored in a prettier path.